# Flex List custom color for rows

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Is it possible to set custom color for rows in a flex list depending on the data in it.I know how to define a custom itemrenderer and do it but I would likr to know whether there is any simple method because I don't want more components in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add custom colors to the itemRenderer that displays your data without modifying, or replacing, the itemRenderer.

The list based classes in Flex use itemRenderers to display data.  If you create your own, then you are replacing the default itemRenderer.  It will not create any more components in memory; it'll just change what those components are.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom list class and by overrideing the protected drawRowBackground method .... you might achive this....

```
protected override function drawRowBackground(s:Sprite, rowIndex:int, y:Number, height:Number, color:uint, dataIndex:int):void {
      if (rowColoringFunction != null && IList(dataProvider).length > dataIndex) {
        color = rowColoringFunction(IList(dataProvider).getItemAt(dataIndex), dataIndex, color);
      }
      super.drawRowBackground(s, rowIndex, y, height, color, dataIndex);
    }
```

try and let me know...